# django + wsgi + python version

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have a django site within virtual environment that uses Python 2.6 installed with Ubuntu. But my django application needs Python 2.7.

I found, that I have to recompile my wsgi for another Python version using `--with-python` option as described at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions

But I wonder if this will be the global wsgi installation? Can I use wsgi+Python2.7 only for specific virtual environment? I would not like to affect other applications on the server.

Comment: Why did you vote down? Maybe any comments? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would affect the global instalation, that is, apache+modwsgi. I don't use apache+modwsgi, but if it is possible to modwsgi to dynamically change the python interpreter (which I doubt it is), this would be a better solution for you.

Another way could be: Check if modwsgi can be configured to be aware of a virtualenv, so it will use the python interpreter of this env, which also I think maybe is not possible because it seems that the python lib is linked into modwsgi library.

Have you considered using other solutions to run your django app?

- [mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org) + [wsgid](http://wsgid.com)
- [nginx](http://nginx.com) + [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org)

in both oy run your app as a **separated** process, and then you can truly use a virtualenv and choose wich python version it will use.

Comment: All virtual environments used with mod_wsgi installation must currently be against same Python version as mod_wsgi was compiled for. This is indeed because mod_wsgi is an embedded system and links the specific version of the Python library. In other words, it doesn't actually invoke the 'python' executable so is hard wired.

Comment: Indeed, I thought this was the case. Thanks @GrahamDumpleton!

Comment: I need quick solution now. Because I'm not familiar with mongrel2 and gunicorn I'd better recompile my wsgi with Python 2.7. Maybe later I will try other solutions.

Anyway, thank you guys, you saved lots of my time.